# How to write a not equal to sign in Latex pseudocode

Tags: syntax, pseudocode

How do I write not equal to sign (equivalent of `!=` in C) in Latex pseudocode.

Comment: Do you mean `$\neq$`?

Comment: Or, what doesn't work for you using `!=`

Answer (score 140):

Not equal can be written as:

```
\neq
```

Comment: `\ne` also works (tested in Typora)

Answer (score 6):

If you want a literal `!=` in a pseudocode listing, you can use `\mathrel{\mathtt{!=}}`.  You could also use ≠ from the monospace font.

Unicode also has the symbol ⍯ from APL.  It’s U+236F, and you can use it in LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

`$\neg$` is - and `$\not=$` is the equal sign with the slash through the center

Answer (score -1):

I would add that if you are using RMarkdown, to have the symbol `≠` translate to a PDF you can use either `$\neq$` or `$\not=$`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!